# Filter 2 arrays

Tags: reactjs

I have an array

```js
let idarray = [55, 25, 24]
```

and another array

```js
let details = [
    {id:55, name:"GHN"},
    {id:46, name:"GTN"},
    {id:78, name:"AHN"},
]
```

I want to filter the object which has id in details aray equal to idarray.How to  filter

Comment: `filter()` and `includes()` should be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let idarray = [55, 25, 24] 

let details = [
    {id:55, name:"GHN"},
    {id:46, name:"GTN"},
    {id:78, name:"AHN"},
]

const result = details.filter(item => {
    return idarray.includes(item.id)
})
```

as the comments suggested includes and filters should do it